# Using a TCPClient object to check if the Windows Firewall itself blocks traffic to an inbound port does not work

Tags: c#, .net, window, port, firewall

**Situation:**

I'm using a .NET TcpClient object to check if the inbound VNC port 5900 is closed on my PC:

TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("localhost", 5900);

This work fine when I'm checking if an inbound port is closed by 3rd party firewall software on my PC. In that case an exception occurs when the port is indeed closed, which I can catch.

**Problem:**

But when I enable the Windows Firewall itself, this method doesn't work because the creation of the connection always succeeds. The exception I just mentioned never occurs in this case.

I also tested this by creating a telnet session to the local host on port 5900. This session doesn't succeed when you use 3rd party firewall to block traffic to the inbound 5900 port. 
This telnet session does succeed though when using the Windows Firewall itself to block traffic.

As expected, creating a VNC connection from another PC on port 5900 doesn't succeed when the windows firewall is enabled (which means the firewall works the way I configured it).

**Questions:**

1. Does anyone know why the windows firewall seems to be working on a different level then 3rd party firewalls?
2. Is there an easy way to solve this? 
   I'd rather not use the Windows Firewall API because then I have to take the different OS versions into account (different API's for XP and Win7)

Comment: Trying to second-guess machine config issues is a rabbit hole.  Provide install instructions or write an installer that opens the port on the firewall.

Comment: That would work, but for me it's one step too far. I want to notify the user about the closed port so he himself can actively open it. My application isn't meant to open the port itself (allthough changing the requirements is an optoion :) ).